# Do i have to create a copy of objects for threads need

Tags: multithreading, rust

I created a two methods one synchronous and one with multiple threads because I wanted to compare performance synchronous and parallel method. But I am having a one issue every time when I want to use my data in threads I have to copy them first even if I know that they want to be dropped till the end of this method. If I do not copy this data before using in threads then I am getting an error that I have to make my data `'static`:

```
fn parallel_kronecker_product(&self, matrix: &Matrix) -> Matrix {
    let product_rows = self.rows_count * matrix.rows_count;
    let product_columns_count = self.columns_count * matrix.columns_count;
    let product = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Matrix::new_zeros_matrix(
        product_rows,
        product_columns_count,
    )));
    let mut handles = vec![];
    for m1_row_index in 0..self.rows_count {
        let product = Arc::clone(&product);
        let matrix_a = self.to_owned();
        let matrix_b = matrix.to_owned();
        handles.push(
            thread::spawn(move || {
                for m1_column_index in 0..matrix_a.columns_count {
                    for m2_row_index in 0..matrix_b.rows_count {
                        for m2_column_index in 0..matrix_b.columns_count {
                            let product_row_index = m1_row_index * matrix_b.rows_count + m2_row_index;
                            let product_column_index =
                                m1_column_index * matrix_b.columns_count + m2_column_index;
                            let mut prod = product.lock().unwrap();
                            (*prod)[product_row_index][product_column_index] = matrix_a[m1_row_index]
                                [m1_column_index]
                                * matrix_b[m2_row_index][m2_column_index];
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        );
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
    return product.lock().unwrap().clone();
}
```

So here I have two matrices. Base which is immutable `self` and one from parameter `matrix`. Inside `for m2_row_index in 0..matrix_b.rows_count` loop I am only multiplying some data which doesn't change original data. Then I iterate over all threads to tell rust to wait until all threads finish their job, so nothing outside this method scope should drop this `matrix`

Can you tell me, what can I do to do not copy this data?

Comment: Peter's answer shows how to apply the answer to the linked question to your case. If this isn't what you're looking for, please [edit] the question to explain how it's different. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scoped thread from a third party crate. There are a few to choose from, but a popular one is from [`crossbeam`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.0/crossbeam/thread/struct.Scope.html). The reason this is needed is because the types used for threads spawned with `std::thread::spawn` do not carry information about how long they last, even if you are explicitly joining them. Crossbeam's scoped threads are bound to the lifetime of the surrounding `Scope` so the borrow checker can be sure that they are finished with borrowed data when the scope ends.

Your provided code has a lot of definitions missing, so I didn't try to compile it, but the general idea would be this:

```
fn parallel_kronecker_product(&self, matrix: &Matrix) -> Matrix {

    // Create a new thread scope and make it own the locals
    thread::scope(move |scope| {
        let product_rows = self.rows_count * matrix.rows_count;
        let product_columns_count = self.columns_count * matrix.columns_count;
        let product = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Matrix::new_zeros_matrix(
            product_rows,
            product_columns_count,
        )));

        let mut handles = vec![];
        for m1_row_index in 0..self.rows_count {
            let product = Arc::clone(&product);
            let matrix_a = self.to_owned();
            let matrix_b = matrix.to_owned();

            // spawn a new thread inside the scope which owns the data it needs to borrow
            handles.push(scope.spawn(move |_| {
                for m1_column_index in 0..matrix_a.columns_count {
                    for m2_row_index in 0..matrix_b.rows_count {
                        for m2_column_index in 0..matrix_b.columns_count {
                            let product_row_index =
                                m1_row_index * matrix_b.rows_count + m2_row_index;
                            let product_column_index =
                                m1_column_index * matrix_b.columns_count + m2_column_index;
                            let mut prod = product.lock().unwrap();
                            (*prod).ind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        for handle in handles {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }

        // probably need a new local binding here. For... reasons...
        let product = product.lock().unwrap().clone();
        product
    }).unwrap()
}
```

Comment: That works, I will learn more about this library. Thank you mate :D